# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'balance' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-redux, onsubmit

I have 5 state objects, an onSubmit function is intended to submit a form with the 5 updated state objects. An onChange method handles the new state and renders to a clients list page.

Below is the class that is triggering an error when i attempt to submit form, with the five updated states. My project is hooked into firestore, i have been unable to narrow down why balance object is undefined.

Ultimately onSubmit should add new client to client list page and create a new client in firestore database.

Can someone help me with this issue, it's my first posting to stackoverflow?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaWqb.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class AddClients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phone: "",
      balance: ""
    };
    //if not using arrow functions bind the method in constructor(initialising it)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //const {firstName,lastName,email,phone,balance} = this.state;
    const { newClient } = this.state;
    const { firestore, history } = this.props;

    if (newClient.balance === "") {
      newClient.balance = 0;
    }
    firestore
      .add({ collection: "clients" }, newClient)
      .then(() => history.push("/"));
  }
  render() {
    // const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, balance } = this.state;
    // console.log(firstName, lastName, email, phone, balance);
    const { disableBalanceOnAdd } = this.props.settings;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-link">
              <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-left" /> Back To Dashboard
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">Add Client</div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="firstName"
                  minLength="2"
                  required={true}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.firstName}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="lastName"
                  minLength="2"
                  required={true}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.lastName}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="phone"
                  minLength="10"
                  required={true}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.phone}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="balance">Balance</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="balance"
                  minLength="1"
                  required={true}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.balance}
                  disabled={disableBalanceOnAdd}
                />
              </div>
              <input
                type="submit"
                value="Submit"
                className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AddClients.propTypes = {
  firestore: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  settings: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default compose(
  firestoreConnect(),
  connect((state, props) => ({
    settings: state.settings
  }))
)(AddClients);
```

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't share screenshots of code or stack traces - please post them as text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing something wrong here. Inside onSubmit function in the line

```
      const { newClient } = this.state;
```

You should assign it as,

```
      const newClient = Object.assign({}, this.state);
```

This will create a copy of this.state object and assign it to newClient const. Then you can access its properties as `newClient.balance`.

Comment: Great to hear that Thomas. Can you accept my answer then?

Comment: I am sorry for well overdue response, thankyou very much